# Change query in Django based on day of week

Tags: python, django

First of all thank you for looking at my question.

I am looking for a way to store the day of week in a model, I have established that having a boolean for each day of the week in the model is likely the most simple approach. I had looked at using bitflags but was unsure again how to query this.

My model looks like the following

```
class CallForwardingRule(models.Model):
    forward_to =  models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False,blank=False)
    start_time = models.TimeField(default=time(0,0))
    end_time = models.TimeField(default=time(0,0))
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    monday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tuesday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    wednesday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thursday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    friday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    saturday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sunday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My query is then like the following

```
CallForwardingRule.objects.filter(start_time__lte=time,end_time__gte=time)
```

What I need to do is alter the query depending on the current day, if the day is monday the query should look for a rule where boolean value monday=True

I hope I have been clear in my question, I am quite new to Django and Python.

Kind Regards

Comment: Can more than one day be True? Why not have a single int weekday field where 0=monday, 1=tuesday, etc? Then you just query `weekday=?`

Comment: Even if several days can be `True`, store them as [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) or as `IntegerField` with values: `1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 4 = Wednesday, etc` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom manager.  Say

```
class TodayManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        today = self.weekday_as_string()
        return super(TodayManager, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            **{today: true})

    def weekday_as_string(self):
        # TODO

class CallForwardingRule(models.Model):
    # your fields

    of_today = TodayManager()
```

And query like this:

```
CallForwardingRule.of_today.filter(
    start_time__lte=time,end_time__gte=time)
```

Read more about object managers here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/

NOTE: If you don't intend for the user to be able to mix days in the same model instance, you should use an integer field with choices instead, as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use an integer or a charfield for your dayofweek. Each of them may be used with choices (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices) which allows you to make it easier to translate the code of the day to its name.

Then, you just have to filter your queryset with this field.